# ManyToMany N+1 problem - All right side not being returned

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have written code that has N+1 problem.
It is a BI-directional ManyToMany relationship.
I'm attempting to solve it using LEFT JOIN FETCH

The issue i am having is that when i look at the results, only 1 single record from the right side is being joined. There should be many more for each left record.

The left records come back correct, but the Set attribute only ever contains 1 instance from the right.

```
      value = "SELECT cat from CatEntity cat "
          + "INNER JOIN cat.owner o "
          + "LEFT JOIN FETCH cat.toys "
          + "WHERE (o.name = :something)
```

I get all 69 cat records, but the cats that have toys only have 1 toy.
If i remove the LEFT JOIN FETCH. I get all cats and all the complete toys... and of course the N+1 problem.
When i add in LEFT JOIN FETCH.. it solves N+1 problem but doesnt return full toy set.

```
public class CatEntity implements Serializable {
  @JoinTable(
      name = "cat_toy",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "cat_id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "toy_id")})
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  @OrderBy(value = "toy_index desc")
  private Set<ToyEntity> toys;
}
}

public class ToyEntity implements Serializable {

 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "toys")
  Set<CatEntity> cats;
}
```

How do i avoid N+1 problem but fully populate the Set?

//Company frowns upon publishing code so i use cat/toy as example replacing class names.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution to my problem. I will post here hoping it helps others.

I was using

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
```

in my code. I needed to use

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
```

This is specifically designed for collections. It populates the right side of a ManyToMany bidirection relationship using 2 queries rather than N+1.

It first gets all the cats. It then gets all the toys. Only 2 queries are executed.

You should NOT put LEFT JOIN FETCH in your query itself. Just add the fetch mode to the entity mapping.

hope this helps others.